# how to define integer size in laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, migration

When I try database migrations Scheme Builder from Laravel.

When I enter a type integer, auto_increment and primary key are automatically inputed.

I don't know how to get a create table in laravel.

```
Schema::create('tbl_corona_region', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->string('seq', 30);
            $table->date('create_dt');
            $table->string('region_nm', 30);
            $table->string('region_cn', 30);
            $table->string('region_en', 30);
            $table->integer('defCnt', 15)->default(0);
            $table->integer('incDec', 15)->default(0);
            $table->integer('deathCnt', 15)->default(0);
            $table->integer('isolIngCnt', 15)->default(0);
            $table->integer('isolClearCnt', 15)->default(0);
            $table->integer('localOccCnt', 15)->default(0);
            $table->integer('overFlowCnt', 15)->default(0);
            $table->integer('qurRate', 15)->default(0);
            $table->dateTime('stdDay');
            $table->dateTime('update_dt');
            $table->primary(['seq', 'create_dt', 'region_nm']);            
        });
```

Generates this SQL

```sql
create table `tbl_corona_region` (
    `seq` varchar(30) not null, 
    `create_dt` date not null, 
    `region_nm` varchar(30) not null, 
    `region_cn` varchar(30) not null, 
    `region_en` varchar(30) not null, 
    `defCnt` int not null default '0' auto_increment primary key, 
    `incDec` int not null default '0' auto_increment primary key, 
    `deathCnt` int not null default '0' auto_increment primary key, 
    `isolIngCnt` int not null default '0' auto_increment primary key, 
    `isolClearCnt` int not null default '0' auto_increment primary key, 
    `localOccCnt` int not null default '0' auto_increment primary key, 
    `overFlowCnt` int not null default '0' auto_increment primary key, 
    `qurRate` int not null default '0' auto_increment primary key, 
    `stdDay` datetime not null, 
    `update_dt` datetime not null
) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

Comment: Because you create $table->primary(['seq', 'create_dt', 'region_nm']);

Comment: You mean `$table->integer('defCnt', 15)->default(0)` would make this field autoincrement and primary?

Comment: Nope I want  only default value 0 not AI and PK on type integer column

Comment: This should not be happening with `integer` though I'm not sure the 2nd parameter should be used there. Can you share the exact Laravel version you are using?

Comment: Directly tell about with sql text


My plan was
create table 'tbl_corona_region' (
 'seq' varchar(30) not null,
 'create_dt' date not null,
 'region_nm' varchar(30) not null,
 'defCnt' int(15) not null default '0' 
.....
 primary key ('seq', 'create_dt', 'region_nm')
)

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter in integer is `autoincrement` not length.

In the laravel database migration, the integer type cannot be specified in length. It takes 11 as default.

The second parameter of the integer method is not the specified length. Instead, the auto increment is set, so the integer method cannot specify the length of the sub-segment.

```
integer(string $column, bool $autoIncrement = false, bool $unsigned =false)
```

Reference : [Laravel core implementation of integer method](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_integer)